# Definir constantes de forma dinámica PHP

Tags: php, variables

Planteando una webapp, tengo una opción por la que pasaría al iniciar sesión y que me crearía unas variables que necesitaría mantener durante todas las páginas, por lo que creo las constantes tal que así:

```
switch($_REQUEST["accion"]){
case 'login':
define("MY_DATA","este es mi valor");
break;
case 'otro':
var_dump(MY_DATA);
break;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo mantener dicha constante? Porque intento usarla en el segundo case y me muestra errores en php diciendo que no está declarada, cuando si se llega ahí se ha pasado previamente por el "login".

Comment: Es necesario que definas constantes?, podrías usar sesiones de PHP y tendrias almacenado esos valores para usarlos mientras este activa la session revisa  https://secure.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `sessiones` de PHP.

Ejemplo básico #1

Registrar una variable con `$_SESSION.`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

Ahora, para tu problema sería lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
session_start();
switch($_POST["accion"]){ //POST o GET
case 'login':
    $_SESSION['MY_DATA'] = "este es mi valor";
    break;
case 'otro':
    var_dump($_SESSION['MY_DATA']);
    break;
} 
?>
```

Las sesiones normalmente se cierran automáticamente cuando PHP termina de ejecutar un script, pero se pueden cerrar manualmente usando la función `session_write_close()`.

Más información acerca de `session_start` https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php

Más información acerca de Uso básico de `sessiones` https://secure.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 6):

Lo mejor en este es el uso de SESSION

```
session_start();
switch($_POST["accion"]){ //POST o GET
case 'login':
    $_SESSION['MY_DATA'] = "este es mi valor";
    break;
case 'otro':
    var_dump($_SESSION['MY_DATA']);
    break;
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Añadiría una validación adicional a las variables `POST` y `GET` para no obtener quizá un `Undefined index`